# TensorFlow.js print whole tensor

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to print a tensor I got using `tf.fromPixels` for debugging purposes. But because the tensor is too big just doing

```
a = tf.fromPixels(image, 3);
a.print();
```

doesn't work, because it is being shortened in the console. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you really only want the values you can use `.data()` or `.dataSync()` to download all values as a one dimensional TypedArray:

```
console.log(a.dataSync());
```

but since your Tensor actually represents an image you can show it visually in a `<canvas>` element:

```
tf.toPixels(a, document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

console.log(type of a)
console.log(a.dataSync());

Comment: Hi there - just a tip, Stackoverflow is compatible with markdown syntax. Enclosing code blocks with "\`" makes them more readable. `An example.`