# model.predict.print() does not show all results in tensorflow.js

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, prediction, tensor, tensorflow.js

after loading the model, the predictions are shown as below:

```
Tensor
    [[0.5050125, 0.6573772],
     [0.5050992, 0.6576715],
     [0.5049844, 0.6572819],
     ...,
     [0.5045587, 0.6558315],
     [0.5050324, 0.6574449],
     [0.5043802, 0.6552206]]
```

How do I make it display all the results instead of "..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this answer on [TensorFlow.js print whole tensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772270/tensorflow)

I could print all the values in the tensor.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
import tensorflow as tf

#Let's create a simulated data...
Tensor=tf.random.normal([10,2])

#...and print every row on screen:
for i in range(len(Tensor)):
    print(Tensor[i].numpy())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However i don't believe this would work in tensorflow.js

Answer (score 0):

**you can use data() method instead of print() method to get all data**

`model.predict(tensorImg).data();`